# Immutable/polymorphic POJO <-> JSON serialization with Jackson

Tags: java, json, inheritance, jackson, immutability

I'm trying to serialize a immutable POJO to and from JSON, using Jackson 2.1.4, without having to write a custom serializer and with as few annotations as possible. I also like to avoid having to add unnecessary getters or default constructors just to satisfy the Jackson library.

I'm now stuck on the exception:

JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class Circle]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)

The code:

```
public abstract class Shape {}


public class Circle extends Shape {
  public final int radius; // Immutable - no getter needed

  public Circle(int radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
  }
}


public class Rectangle extends Shape {
  public final int w; // Immutable - no getter needed
  public final int h; // Immutable - no getter needed

  public Rectangle(int w, int h) {
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
}
```

The test code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY); // Adds type info

Shape circle = new Circle(10);
Shape rectangle = new Rectangle(20, 30);

String jsonCircle = mapper.writeValueAsString(circle);
String jsonRectangle = mapper.writeValueAsString(rectangle);

System.out.println(jsonCircle); // {"@class":"Circle","radius":123}
System.out.println(jsonRectangle); // {"@class":"Rectangle","w":20,"h":30}

// Throws:
//  JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found.
//  Can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
Shape newCircle = mapper.readValue(jsonCircle, Shape.class);
Shape newRectangle = mapper.readValue(jsonRectangle, Shape.class);

System.out.println("newCircle = " + newCircle);
System.out.println("newRectangle = " + newRectangle);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could (according to the API) annotate the constructor with [@JsonCreator](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) and the parameters with [@JsonProperty](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html).

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
    public final int radius; // Immutable - no getter needed

    @JsonCreator
    public Circle(@JsonProperty("radius") int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}

public class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public final int w; // Immutable - no getter needed
    public final int h; // Immutable - no getter needed

    @JsonCreator        
    public Rectangle(@JsonProperty("w") int w, @JsonProperty("h") int h) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }
}
```

Edit: Maybe you have to annotate the Shape class with [@JsonSubTypes](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSubTypes.html) so that the concrete subclass of Shape could be determined.

```
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(Circle.class), @JsonSubTypes.Type(Rectangle.class)})
public abstract class Shape {}
```

Comment: Looked promising, but now I get the following exception instead: JsonMappingException: Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for Circle, annotations: {interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator()}] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-paramater constructor annotated as Creator

Comment: Although the @JsonProperty annotation is present?

Comment: Yes, like in your example. On all constructor arguments.

Comment: Strange, I will have a closer look at this tomorrow. Until then you could try if changing your fields visibility to private (and adding getter methods) solves the problem (like in this example: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations#using-constructors-or-factory-methods). Another question: Are your classes nested?

Comment: Yes - you are right! The classes were nested (in my test case) and needed 'static' to work! So, everything's working perfectly now! Funny thing, it did not need JsonCreator nor JsonSubTypes to work. The only annotation needed was the JsonProperty! Thanks!

Comment: It makes sense when you consider that non-static inner classes have "hidden" first argument that passes 'this' pointer to parent class. This is compiler-induced syntactic sugar that allows non-static inner classes to refer to instance fields of enclosing parent class instance.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/GettingStarted) library some of its key features are adressing your exact problem: polymorphism, not requiring annotations and most important immutable pojos. Everything works in your example with 0 annotations or heavy conf.

```
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().setWithClassMetadata(true)
                            .setWithDebugInfoPropertyNameResolver(true)
                            .create();

String jsonCircle = genson.serialize(circle);
String jsonRectangle = genson.serialize(rectangle);

System.out.println(jsonCircle); // {"@class":"your.package.Circle","radius":123}
System.out.println(jsonRectangle); // {"@class":"your.package.Rectangle","w":20,"h":30}

// Throws nothing :)
Shape newCircle = genson.deserialize(jsonCircle, Shape.class);
Shape newRectangle = genson.deserialize(jsonRectangle, Shape.class);
```

Genson gives you also the ability to use aliases (used instead classes names).

```
new Genson.Builder().addAlias("shape", Shape.class)
                .addAlias("circle", Circle.class)
                .create();
```

Answer (score 1):

Rectangle has two parameters, and the [FAQ](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#Data_Binding.2C_reading_.28de-serialization.29) says:

> **Deserializing simple types**
>
> If I want to deserialize simple JSON values (Strings, integer /
>   decimal numbers) into types other than supported by default, do I need
>   to write a custom deserializer?
>
> Not necessarily. If the class to deserialize into has one of:
>
> - Single-argument constructor with matching type (String, int/double), or
> - Single-argument static method with name "valueOf()", and matching argument type
>
> Jackson will use such method, passing in matching JSON value as
>   argument.

I'm afraid you have to write your own [deserializer as show in the Jackson documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule testModule =
   new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null))
      .addDeserializer( MyType.class, new MyTypeDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule( testModule );
```