# POST to Spring MVC controller results in "HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: No suitable constructor found"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-boot

I am using Spring MVC via Spring Boot 1.2.

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class Person {
    final private String name;

    /* 
     * Cannot include this constructor because `name` is `final`.
     *
    public Person() {}
     */

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And this `RestController`:

```
@RestController
public class PeopleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public Person createPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return person; 
    }
}
```

**I'd like the framework to take the `name` attribute of the JSON object I POST, and use that to construct my `Person` instance.** But, when I try to POST to this controller like,

```
$ curl -XPOST -d '{ "name": "Dmitry" }' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:8080/person
```

I get this error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class example.Person]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable
 type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4e7fa67d; line: 1, column: 3]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class example.Person]: 
can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
// Trace ommitted
```

Searching on the Web, people say I need to include an empty constructor. But I can't do that, given the nature of my model, which has `final` properties that need to be set in the constructor.

So, what are my options for fixing this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Annotate your `Person` constructor parameter with `@JsonProperty`.

```
public Person(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if @JsonCreator is necessary? It's working without it, but the docs say it's necessary.

Comment: @dimadima Necessary for your constructor? No, it should not be needed.

Comment: So now I get a 415 Unsupported Media exception like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548182/spring-rest-httpmediatypenotsupportedexception-content-type-application-json. Not sure how do fix this because I have `consumes = application/json` and `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`. What do you think?

Comment: @dimadima Send an `Accept: application/json` header as well. I'm not sure what `curl` sends by default, if any.

Comment: It sends `*/*` by default. I overrode that with `application/json` but that didn't help. The exception occurs at at `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:152)`

Comment: @dimadima Oh, nevermind. I was thinking 406. Are you registering any custom `HttpMessageConverter`s? Please edit your question with your configuration and the stack trace.

Comment: Nope, no custom converters.

Comment: Figured out my problem: my model was a non-static inner class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121643/immutable-polymorphic-pojo-json-serialization-with-jackson

Comment: This worked for me. I don't know why it doesn't work without it.